# Using capacitor to maintain current flow past opening of switch

Tags: capacitor, motor, timer

This circuit turns on the motor when something blocks the beam from the LED to the phototransistor. I want the motor to remain on for 5 seconds after the beam stops being blocked (i.e. from when the phototransistor resumes conducting).

[image]

I first thought to add a capacitor in parallel with the motor, but 9V/(.120A * 5s) = 15F (I think?)

So then I thought to put the capacitor where it is highlighted in the circuit diagram, but I don't know how to determine what capacitor to use.

1. Will the capacitor charge in a few seconds in this arrangement? What if its positive terminal goes above the 1K resistor?
2. What size capacitor do I need? (The transistor is 2N2222). I'd love to see how this is calculated, but given how hairy the math seems to get with capacitor discharge there might be some rule of thumb?

I'm new to this, so would appreciate having any errors I made pointed out to me.

Comment: Check this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48968/time-delay-circuit-keeping-line-high

Answer (score 2):

Don't use 2N2222, use 2N7000 MOSFETs (that motor must be small) and it will be much easier. Try this:

[image]

You will have to tweak the value of R5 to fine tune the timing. D2 is there to avoid C1 discharging through anything that isn't R5, and to charge C1 as fast as possible. The time constant between R5 and C1 determines the turn-off time.

This circuit could be improved by doing a harder switching action on M1 to lower switching losses, but if it is not switched on-off very frequently, it will work fine.

Oh, and dont forget about the flywheel diode D3, the motor inductive spike can be very nasty.

Comment: What is the advantage to using 2N7000 over 2N2222? What change to the circuit would have to be made to keep using the 2N2222?

Comment: As the FET starts to turn off is there any possibility that it might exceed its power rating of 300mW? The turn-off is a slowish decay of the gate voltage and this may cause dissipation problems. It would be the same with a BJT of course. The best solution (that protects the fet) is to use a comparator and quite possibly this is a 555 timer job. I don't think i'd rely on this circuit.

Comment: @Guest - the FET has a high impedance input (gate) and this makes it more convenient to use (compared to a BJT) when charging and discharging capacitors on its gate.

Comment: Good point @Andy-aka, that's why I say that this circuit could be improved. I have found this kind of circuit to work fine if switching is not very frequent because that 300mW (400mW actually) power rating is DC based, if the power dissipated is in pulse form, the device's thermal capacity allows it to hold for an extra bit of power. But you are essentialy right, you have to take care of that. Indeed, using a 555 or other (there are many and better) monostable could give better performance. I have to admit that I like the simplicity of this circuit, and if well dimensioned, will be rock solid.

Comment: @payala You might also point out that the RC time constant of charging the capacitor is determined by R3 and C1, and is 33mS. The capacitor needs to be fully charged to keep the motor going for 5s, and it only charges when the light is blocked, so the light needs to be blocked for at least 100ms. That may or may not be an important consideration...we don't know how the OP is planning to use the circuit.